# Largest product in a series Project Euler #8

Tags: java

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

My Solution is below and works fine. I want to know how can I improve/optimise my solution? I can use any data structures.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;

public class ProjectEuler8 {

final static String digits_1000 = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
static Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
static long prod=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    for(int i=0; i<digits_1000.length(); i++ ){

        int curr = Character.getNumericValue(digits_1000.charAt(i));
        if(curr==0){
            q.clear();
            continue;
        }

        if(q.size() == 13){

            q.remove();
            q.add(curr);

            long tmpProd = Library.getProductOfAllInQueue(q);
            if(tmpProd>prod){
                prod=tmpProd;
            }
        }else{
            q.add(curr);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("greatest product are : " + prod);

    long stop = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("\nTime: " + (stop - start) / 1000 + " ns");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Instead of re-calculating the product of all 13 digits each iteration, it'd be faster to divide out the digit being dropped and multiply in the next digit. That'll get rid of the need for a queue; all you need is the current product.

2) If you see a `0` you should just skip ahead 13 digits and start fresh. It's a small optimization. More importantly, it avoids a divide by zero problem with (1).

Comment: If you see a '0', skip ahead to the position just after the '0', which might be less than 13 positions.

Comment: @rossum To get to the position after the `0` you need to skip past 13 digits.